# simple http server

Tags: c#, .net, http

I have a server client application.
The clients sends the  server http posts with info every second or so.
The server is implemented using C#, there server doesn't need to respond in any way to the client.

Whats the easiest and most practical way to get this done? Is there some kind of library that is easy to use that I can import into my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a regular old web service?  It sounds like you have simple functionality that doesn't need to maintain a connection state.  With a web service, you can simply expose the methods to your client, accessible via HTTP/S.  If you're already using .NET for your client, you can simply add a web reference to your project and have .NET do the heavy lifting for you.  There wouldn't be any need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Do I need ISS to host the web service?

I want to be able to distribute the server app to simple stupid users...

Comment: If you're planning on using ASP.NET, then yes you need IIS.  Why would you be distributing your server to other users?

Answer (score 1):

You can use http.sys to create your own http listener without IIS or additional overhead. Aaron Skonnard has a good article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163879.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Because of certain limitations of uhttpsharp (specifically no support for POST forms and file uploads and it using threads to process requests), I've made [NHttp available at github](http://github.com/pvginkel/NHttp) which supports full request parsing like ASP.net and processes requests using the asynchronous TCP model.